# Синтаксис вызова findViewById()

Tags: java, android

В книгах по основам `Java` было написано, что для вызова метода нужно указать сначала ссылку на объект, а потом после точки сам метод. Если же метод статический то указывается класс, а потом после точки метод. А в книге по `Android` читаю
`TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);`. Почему не указывается ни класс ни объект? Это из-за того, что объявление метода находится в том же классе что и вызов? Или же это просто упрощение, а `AndroidStudio` в дальнейшем при сборке сама добавляет всё что нужно?

Comment: у вас есть класс А, в нем есть метод method() Когда вы внутри другого метода класса А хотите вызвать свой method() не надо ставить точку, т.к. работа происходит внутри класса. А если  вы хотите вызвать метод из вне. из класса Б например. то тогда внутри класса Б надо создавать экземпляр класса А и к нему через точку применять метод

Answer (score 5, accepted):

метод [`findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) - метод класса `Activity` (и ее наследников), поэтому при вызове данного метода в классе активити указывать экземпляр класса нет необходимости, это ее собственный метод. Если вы непременно хотите поставить точку и обатиться к объекту, то можете вызывать этот метод у текущего экземпляра класса:

```
Button btn = this.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Если найти элемент на разметке нужно не в пределах активити, а в фрагменте, диалоге (эти классы не содержат собственного метода `findViewById()`) или другом `ViewGroup`, то для поиска необходимо использовать тот экземпляр `ViewGroup`, в котором предположительно находится данный элемент, например в фрагменте:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
            Button btn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    return rootView;
}
```

в этих случаях [используется метод `findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) класса `View`, а не `Activity` и указывать экземпляр класса, в котором осуществлять поиск обязательно, так как поиск осуществляется за пределами экземпляра класса `View`

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio тут не причём. Это так будет работать в любой IDE или даже в Блокноте.

> Это из-за того что объявление метода находится в том же классе что и
>   вызов?

Да, всё верно. Метод `public View findViewById(@IdRes int id)` объявлен в классе `Activity`. Поэтому, если вы вызываете его внутри класса `Activity` или любого из его наследников, например `AppCompatActivity`, `FragmentActivity` и т.д., то вы сразу пишете название метода:

```
TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

Также можно явно указать экземпляр класса:

```
TextView brands = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

В данном случае эти два выражения эквивалентны.

Но вот `Fragment` не является наследником класса `Activity`, поэтому мы не можем использовать этот метод тем же способом внутри фрагмента. Вместо этого мы вызываем этот метод у `View`, которая также не является наследником `Activity`, но имеет такой же метод, который ни как не связан с методом активити, хотя и называется точно также:

```
TextView brands = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка на view пишется так `findViewById(R.id.(id обьекта))`

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

Попробуем разобрать

`TextView brands` - `TextView` это тип данных, класс, которому должна соответствовать переменная `brands`.

`(TextView)` - К данному типу данных, класса, вы приводите то значение, которое будет сформировано в вызове функции `findViewById`, параметром которой является `id` созданного вами `View` (в данном случае `TextView`) в `layout`-представлении.

[findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) - public метод вашего Активити, поэтому он вызывается без объекта с точкой впереди.

Comment: человек не об этом спрашивает